# In project created with "generator-angular-fullstack", how to filter list items (in server side)?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, bluebird, angular-fullstack

I am using [generator-angular-fullstack](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack):

```
npm install -g generator-Angular-Fullstack@3.2.0
```

Created project with settings:
Out of the box I create an AngularJS app with an Express server.

## Client

? What would you like to write markup with? **HTML**
? What would you like to write stylesheets with? **CSS**
? What Angular router would you like to use? **uiRouter**
? Would you like to include Bootstrap? **Yes**
? Would you like to include UI Bootstrap? **Yes**

## Server

? What would you like to use for data modeling? **Mongoose (MongoDB)**
? Would you scaffold out an authentication boilerplate? **Yes**
? Would you like to include additional oAuth strategies? **Facebook, Twitter**
? Would you like to use socket.io? **Yes**

## Project

? What would you like to write tests with? (Use arrow keys)?  **Jasmine**

I created new endpoint "Reservations":

```
yo angular-fullstack:endpoint reservation       //Server side
yo angular-fullstack:route reservatios //Client Route
```

Updated that  new page were populated "reservatios"  list. 
But it gets all "Reservation" items.

I want to get all reservations when user isAdmin.
**In other cases (non users, or simple users) I want to get only active Reservations.**

So there is simple Reservation model:

```
var ReservationSchema = new Schema({
   date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  }
  //,user: {
  //  type : Schema.ObjectId,
  //  ref : 'User'
  //}
});
```

**Reservations is active**, when the "new Date()" < reservatio.date.

So there is these server side controllers:
server\api\reservation\   reservation.controller.js

where these methods are like:

```
// Gets a list of Reservations
export function index(req, res) {
  Reservation.findAsync()
    .then(responseWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

So I created one more function for ActiveReservations:

```
// Gets a list of Active Reservations
export function active(req, res) {
  Reservation.findAsync()
    .then(getOnlyActive(res))
    .then(responseWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

So I added this custom functio "**getOnlyActive(res)**".

***My question:***
What should be in that function, how to filter "res", to get only active reservations? I think the filtering should be done here. Correct my and point to correct approatch how to get filtered items from mongoDB (using mongoose).

Comment: You should really read the docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Comment: So how I understand these queries is in bluebird promisive style:
var mongoose = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));
I am newby to mongodb and this bluebird. So it was good to get full example how the filtering should be done in written case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally find out how to do filtering :)...

In example this was my model (server\api\reservation\reservation.model.js):

```
var mongoose = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ReservationSchema = new Schema({
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  }
});

export default mongoose.model('Reservation', ReservationSchema);
```

I added new static function to it:

```
ReservationSchema.statics.findActive = function (next) {
    return this.find({"date": {"$gte": new Date()}});
};
```

Then added the new function to reservation controller (server\api\reservation\reservation.controller.js)

```
// Gets a list of Active Reservations
export function active(req, res) {
    Reservation.findActive()
    .execAsync()
    .then(responseWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

Finally added route for active reservations (server\api\reservation\index.js):

```
router.get('/active', controller.active);
```

Now it works :). Check by calling in browser:

http://localhost:9000/api/reservations    // Gets all reservations
http://localhost:9000/api/reservations/active  // Gets only active reservations - with is "reservation.date > new Date()".